# UWP BackgroundUploaderContentPart empty value

Tags: uwp, httprequest

I am trying to pass a `null` `string`, or empty `string` to `BackgroundUploaderContentPart` using `SetText()` method. However, upon reaching that line, the code crashes and says there is a value exception. I am guessing it wants it to be non-`null`. Is there a way to pass a `null`/empty value? I tried `SetHeader` method with same outcome.

Answer (score 0):

You can't pass a null into [BackgroundTransferContentPart](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.networking.backgroundtransfer.backgroundtransfercontentpart#Methods).
A [BackgroundTransferContentPart](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.networking.backgroundtransfer.backgroundtransfercontentpart#Methods) must contain a file or text. If must, you can mark a string as a null tag, then your server can identify the string tag as null.

Comment: Just to clarify. I should designate a string, for example "null" (or any other that normally won't occur in the case) to be the null string and then send that and the server should recognise it and deal with it as if it was null? Also, is this a bug, since Windows.Web.Http seems to support an empty string in the HttpMultipartFormDataContent .

Comment: @Edged Yes, that is what I mean. Otherwise, this is by design but not a bug, it requires the BackgroundTransferContentPart contain a file or text as content to upload.